# Windows7: Last files listing in start menu

Tags: windows-7, start-menu, list

In Windows 7 there is a list of most frequent programs and for each program there is a list of recent files using them.

Here, you can see, for example, list of last files opened in TeXmaker. The last file actually opened is not on this list though. `MetodyStruers.tex` is the third recent file opened in TeXmaker.

[image]

Is there a way how to keep this list up to date?

**EDIT**

The command:

```
del /F /Q %APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\AutomaticDestinations\*
```

just deleted all the recent lists. The conclusion is, that the list is system-maintained. Individual programs keep their own lists elsewhere.

To update the list I have tried:

- Double-click in explorer (Salamander). No effect;
- Right-click -> Open With... -> %Program. Success;
- File -> Open... Success;
- File -> Open recent. No effect;
- File -> New; File -> Save. Success;
- File -> Save. No effect;
- File -> Save as... Success.

This raised another questions:

- What is The Difference between `Open` and `Open with >` commands in context menu?
- What is The Difference between `Save` and `Save as` commands in the
  program?
- What is The Difference between `Open` and `Open Recent` commands?

Answer (score 2):

You should try to reset your recent list of files, and hope that this will resolve your issue

```
del /F /Q %APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\AutomaticDestinations\*
```

and for custom

```
del /F /Q %APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\CustomDestinations\*
```

Comment: It just deleted the lists. The only ways to append the file to the list, I have found, is to use File->Open dialog or File->new and File->Save. If I open it using File->Recent, nothing happened. Same result for opening the file from explorer (Salamander).